# UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag and CFStringRef in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

```
import Foundation
import MobileCoreServices

func checkFileExtension(fileName: NSString){
    println(fileName)

    var fileExtension:CFStringRef = fileName.pathExtension

    println(fileExtension)

    var fileUTI:CFStringRef = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, nil)

    println(fileUTI)

    let testBool = UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage) != 0

    if  testBool{
        println("image")
    }
}
```

I get this error

> error : 'Unmanaged' is not convertible to 'CFStringRef'

at line

> var fileUTI:CFStringRef = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, nil)

any ideas ?? Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag` passes back an [`Unmanaged<CFStringRef>`](http://swifter.natecook.com/type/Unmanaged/), so you need to get the value out of the `Unmanaged` object before you can use it:

```
var unmanagedFileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, nil)
var fileUTI = unmanagedFileUTI.takeRetainedValue()
```

Note that I'm calling `takeRetainedValue()` since `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag` is returning an object that we are responsible for releasing. The comments on `takeRetainedValue()` say:

> Get the value of this unmanaged reference as a managed reference and
>   consume an unbalanced retain of it.
>
> This is useful when a function returns an unmanaged reference and you
>   know that you're responsible for releasing the result.

If you get an `Unmanaged` object back from a function where you are sure you **aren't** responsible for releasing that object, call `takeUnretainedValue()` instead.

Comment: The choice of takeRetainedValue vs takeUnretainedValue depends only (as I understand the docs) on whether the Core Foundation function returns a (+1) retained object or not. UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag() has "Create" in its name, so according to the memory management rules that returns a (+1) retained object which the caller has to release eventually. So you have to call takeRetainedValue here, otherwise the object would never be released and you have a leak.

Comment: Compare "Create Rule" in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer! really helped me!

Comment: @MartinR You're right, I mis-read the comments on `takeUnretainedValue()` and got it backwards.  I'll fix that...

Comment: Another very clear explanation is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29049072/250164

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention a little module I published that deals exactly with this kind of thing in a much nicer way. Your example would become:

```c
import SwiftUTI

func checkFileExtension(fileURL: URL){

    let uti = UTI(withExtension: fileURL.pathExtension)

    if uti.conforms(to: .image) {

        print("image")
    }
}
```

It's available here: https://github.com/mkeiser/SwiftUTI