# Custom IntentResponse return image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sirikit, sirishortcuts

My app should donate a shortcut to the shortcuts app, to retrieve a random image.
However I am unable to return an image, and do understand how it should be done.

My intents file is as following. As "image" aint a possible return type, I instead return a file.

[image]

My code:

```
class TestIntentHandler: NSObject, TestIntentIntentHandling {
        func handle(intent: TestIntentIntent, completion: @escaping (TestIntentIntentResponse) -> Void) {
            let response = TestIntentIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
            let data = UIImage(named: "test")!.pngData()!
            response.image = INFile(data: data, filename: "tester", typeIdentifier: "png")
            completion(response)
        }
        
      func confirm(intent: TestIntentIntent, completion: @escaping (TestIntentIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        completion(TestIntentIntentResponse(code: .ready, userActivity: nil))
      }
}
```

But testing the shortcut dont show the image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Tried to run the same kind of code, and found that Shortcut recognizes the file as image if you give it the right `typeIdentifier` (UTI) while creating the `INFile` object. For example, to show a PNG file, you would use `"public.png"`

Here's an example of Shortcut showing a action result as an image
[image: An image being shown as an action result]

Now your question could be *"Where do I get those identifiers from?"*. Well, that depends on your target iOS version. You could use UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(iOS <14) or UTType (iOS 14+), extract it directly from the URL if it contains it, [or you can read the Apple reference list here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)

i'll leave here the UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag example, courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26635805/2370982)

```
let fileExtension = "png" // This could be extracted from an URL
let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(
    kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,
    fileExtension,
    nil)
```

... and the URL example, courtesy of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34772517/2370982)

```
extension URL {
    var typeIdentifier: String? { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier }
    var localizedName: String? { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.localizedNameKey]))?.localizedName }
}
```